# How can an audio wave be represented in a long array of floats?

Tags: audio

In my application I'm using the sound library Beads (this question *isn't* specifically about that library).

In the library there's a class `WavePlayer`. It takes a `Buffer`, and produces a sound wave by iterating over the `Buffer`.

`Buffer`s simply wrap a `float[]`.

For example, here's a beginning of a buffer:

```
0.0 0.0015339801 0.0030679568 0.004601926 0.0061358847 0.007669829 0.009203754 0.010737659 0.012271538 0.0138053885 0.015339206 0.016872987 0.01840673 0.019940428 0.02147408  ...
```

It's size is 4096 `float` values.

Iterating over it with a `WavePlayer` creates a smooth "sine wave" sound. (This buffer is actually a ready-made 'preset' in the `Buffer` class, i.e. `Buffer.SINE`).

My question is:

What kind of data does a buffer like this represent? What kind of information does it contain that allows one to iterate over it and produce an audio wave?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a different SE site. They didn’t exist when this question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

read this post [What's the actual data in a WAV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940376/whats-the-actual-data-in-a-wav-file)

Sound is just a curve.  You can represent this curve using integers or floats.

There are two important aspects : bit-depth and sample-rate.  First let's discuss bit-depth.  Each number in your list (int/floats) represents the height of the sound curve at a given point in time.  For simplicity, when using floats the values typically vary from -1.0 to +1.0  whereas integers may vary from say 0 to 2^16  Importantly,  each of these numbers must be stored into a sound file or audio buffer in memory - the resolution/fidelity you choose to represent each point of this curve influences the audio quality and resultant sound file size.  A low fidelity recording may use 8 bits of information per curve height measurement. As you climb the fidelity spectrum, 16 bits,  24 bits ... are dedicated to store each curve height measurement. More bits equates with more significant digits for floats or a broader range of integers (16 bits means you have 2^16 integers (0 to 65535) to represent height of any given curve point).

Now to the second aspect  sample-rate.  As you capture/synthesize sound in addition to measuring the curve height, you must decide how often you measure (sample) the curve height.  Typical CD quality records (samples) the curve height 44100 times per second, so sample-rate would be 44.1kHz. Lower fidelity would sample less often, ultra fidelity would sample at say 96kHz or more.  So the combination of curve height measurement fidelity (bit-depth) coupled with how often you perform this measurement (sample-rate) together define the quality of sound synthesis/recording

As with many things these two attributes should be in balance ... if you change one you should change the other ... so if you lower sample rate you are reducing the information load and so are lowering the audio fidelity ... once you have done this you can then lower the bit depth as well without further compromising fidelity